# Is there any way to use NSPredicate to filter objects using distance calculation between points in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

For example I have NSManagedObject with x and y double values. I want to get list of point that are located on some distance from provided one. I tried to use next predicate:

[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(x-%f)*(x-%f)-(y-%f)*(y-%f) <= %f", point.x, point.x, point.y, point.y, 25*25] . But it doesn't work for some reason :(( .

In my experiments I found out that predicate like (x-1)*2-x >= 0 returns 0 objects even if x is greater than 1, and (x+1)*2-x >= 0 returns all objects. So I suspect that calculations in predicate is not supported, but there are no information about it anywhere I looked

Comment: I'm not so sure but there is some kind of keyword called "FUNCTION" http://moottoot.blogspot.it/2008/01/oooh-nspredicate-functions.html

Comment: Thanks for reply, but functions are not supported for SQLite store type. It seems that I'll have to do it in several steps. First filtering for a (x1+r>x2 AND x1-r<x2) AND (y1+r>y2 AND y1-r<y2) and than filter the resulting array